# How do you create embedded documents using FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mongoid, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl and RSpec to test my code. Mongoid in my ORM. The problem I am encountering is that in order create an embedded document, you must also create the parent document. Here is an example:

```
# app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title

  embeds_many :ingredients
end

# app/models/ingredient.rb
class Ingredient
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name

  embedded_in :recipe
end
```

Then I make factories for both of these:

```
# spec/factories/recipes.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :recipe do |f|
    f.title "Grape Salad"
    f.association :ingredient
  end
end

# spec/factories/ingredients.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ingredient do |f|
    f.name "Grapes"
  end
end
```

The problem I have now is that I cannot ever call FactoryGirl.create(:ingredient). The reason being that `Ingredient` is embedded, and my `Ingredient` factory never declares the association to the Recipe. If I do declare an association to the recipe, then I get an infinite loop because the Recipe associates with the Ingredient, and the Ingredient associates with the Recipe. The is quite annoying because I can't unit test my Ingredient class correctly. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is simply to unit-test the embedded Ingredient class, then it would be best to avoid doing a 'create' into the database altogether, and simply instantiate the object ala...

```
FactoryGirl.build(:ingredient)
```

That would avoid actually persisting the object into MongoDB.  Otherwise, from a Mongoid/MongoDB perspective the embedded document can't exist in the database without the parent, so if you must persist the object into the DB you will have to do it via the parent.